# Do we have a way to apply multiple format to numbers in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is quite simple, I have a number: e.g. `x = 123.234`

Now what I want to do is:
 1. change to 2 decimal places: `123.23`;
 2. add 2 zeros in the front: `00123.45`;
 3. add 2 x-s in the end: `00123.45xx`;
 4. and if my x changes to `x = 1234.2345`, then my final output will be `01234.2345x`

I know how to get the answer with some code, but I just want to ask, is there a way, which I can combine all the formats into 1 line, like:

```
"{:.2f,0>A,x<B}".format(number)
```

where A,B are some value you can set

then it will give me a string, though kind of meaningless, 00123.45xx

Comment: You want to *pad* the number with two zeros to a specific length, or you want to *always* add exactly two zeros…?

Comment: What prevents you from writing the ``00`` and ``xx`` before and after the format placeholder?

Comment: with a specific length which can be set by myself... with exactly 2 zeros/x i can just '00' + string + 'xx' no problem...maybe my question is too odd :)

Comment: You want to pad 0's in front, and x's at the back of a (floating point) number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am using this code:

```
x = 13.23456

k = "{:x<10s}".format("{:0>8.2f}".format(x))
print(k) #00013.23xx
```

and if you change the length of x, the total length of the result keeps the same while still have 0 and x:

```
x = 123.23456

k = "{:x<10s}".format("{:0>8.2f}".format(x))
print(k) #00123.23xx
```

seems we do not have a way to combine {:x<10s} and {:0>8.2f} into one:

```
#not possible: {:0>8.2f, x<10s}.format(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to *pad* the number to a specific length with zeros:

```
'{:0>8.2f}'.format(123.234)  # 00123.23
```

If you always want to add exactly 2 zeros:

```
'00{:.2f}'
```

And that should also make it obvious how to apply two trailing xxs:

```
'00{:.2f}xx'
```

Comment: yes I know we can get 00123.23 by using '{:0>8.2f}'.format(123.234); and we can get 123.23xx by using '{:x<8.2f}'.format(123.234), but seems we cannot simply combine these two format into one...

Comment: You want to *centre align* with different padding on the left and the right…?

Comment: maybe another example: you can change x=5 into x = +5.00 by using "{:+.2f}".format(x), you can also change x = 5 into x = 05 by using "{:0>2d}".format(x); but if I want to change x = 5 into x = +05.00, seems we cannot use "{:+2f, 0>2d}".format(x), we cannot indicate multiple format in that {}

Comment: It would really help if you could formalise your expectation to a simple English sentence, like "centre-align with different pre and post paddings"…

Comment: sorry for my bad description, what I want is: to apply multiple format to a number, in a way of "{:arg1, arg2, arg3,}".format(x), then return me a string I want. But seems this function does not exist. like in my question, if i want "00123.23xx", i can say "{:.2f, x<8f, 0>10f}".format(x)

Comment: "Applying multiple formats" is just a *means to an end*. It doesn't describe what you're *actually* trying to do. For any one specific end goal, there may be a very concise way to do it with a format string; but for other goals such a format string doesn't exist and you need to use some other solution. In general, no, "multiple formats" isn't a thing, but there's probably a closely related solution. Also see http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: anyway, thanks for your patience and time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 2):

With variable precision, pre-width and post-width:

```
>>> "{:0>{prewidth}.{prec}f}{:x<{postwidth}s}".format(123.456, '', prec=2, prewidth=8, postwidth=2)
'00123.45xx'
```

or variants thereof.

See also the [PyFormat page](https://pyformat.info/#param_align).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = 123.456
>>> A = 5
>>> B = 2
>>> '{:0{}.{}f}'.format(x,A+B+1,B)+('X'*(str(x)[::-1].find('.')-B))
'00123.46X'

>>> x = 1234.5678
>>> A = 7
>>> B = 2
>>> '{:0{}.{}f}'.format(x,A+B+1,B)+('X'*(str(x)[::-1].find('.')-B))
'0001234.57XX'
```

Upside of this: Completely modular.
`A` is total numbers in front of the `.`, `B` is the number of decimals that should not be `X`. The rest of the decimals are `X`.

Comment: Sure. TBH I'm only on here to learn working other peoples problems :)